# Provide path to XmlElement when Deserialize C#

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I have an xml like this

```
  <order>
    <id>1</id>
    <location>
      <city>
       Test
      </city>
      <state>
      </state>
    </location>
  </order>
```

and an order class like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ordertransaction") ]
    class Order{
     [XmlElement("id")]
     public String id {get;set;}
     [XmlElement("location/city")]
     public String city {get;set;}
    }
```

Is it possible to access the "city" tag without having to create a location class when deserializing?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that. The class has to have the same structure as the xml.